# How to generate URLs to link back to objects?

Tags: spray

I'm trying to build some RESTful services using spray.  I've figured out how to build the directives I need.  But the issue I'm having is how to reliable generate URLs back to the "resources" I'm working with.  Note I use the term "resources" here as it is used for RESTful APIs (i.e. the server side objects one refers to through the API).

I've looked through the documentation and I haven't found any reference for this except mention of "Resources" in the Java sense (i.e. data files in the classpath).

For sure I can build a directive that maps "/items/127" to a resource on the server side.  But what I don't see how to do (at least in a safe and automatic way) in Spray is how to generate such a URL given the server-side resource.  I'm looking for something similar to `url_for` from the Flask framework.

For now, I'm writing functions to do this.  But, of course, they are fragile because they aren't DRY (i.e. they don't use any knowledge of Spray routing in generating the URLS).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is known as reverse routing. As @iwein said, there's no direct support for reverse routing in Spray. You can confirm this from [Matthias in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spray-user/reverse$20routing/spray-user/S0dGTKUcrOE/kVO0CctQXFsJ). There is an [open ticket for this issue](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/941).

However, there is an approach, based on the PathMatcher that Marcel Mojzis open sourced which you can find [here](https://bitbucket.org/binarycamp/spray-contrib/src/master/spray-data/src/main/scala/binarycamp/spray/data/ResourceLocator.scala).

I have a need for this as well, but I'm going to get by with a "known pattern" approach until Spray (or akka-http) comes up with its own solution to this issue. Essentially, I have an object that knows how to generate the URL for certain patterns of things. Each pattern is a function and clients of the object have to ask for the url by one of the function names. Not ideal, but very simple and effective until akka-http provides a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Spray has an equivalent of url_for. I don't think it would make sense in the context of Spray, because in Spray you're not annotating functions with urls that map to them, but you're creating routes that deserialize requests and eventually map them to functions.

As such there is no easy way to generate an example url from the name of a function.